# What is the size my different datastore entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I wanted to view the size of my datastore entities OR be able to estimate them some how?
(I cant see where memory size info is on Appstats Console or the Development Console?)

My problem is that I want to know the byte size of 2 types of entities:

***Entity A***

- The key_name is 20 characters. (ie. {AAAA}*{BBBB}*{CCCC} ).
- Only one TextProperty
  of 1 character (ie. "0" ).

***Entity B***

- Same as above. The key_name is 20
  characters. (ie '{AAAA}*{BBBB}*{CCCC}
  ).
- Only one TextProperty of 65536
  characters long.

Any help on finding current entity sizes AND/OR estimating entity sizes is appreciated. THANKS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len(db.model_to_protobuf(entity).Encode())`

Comment: Although you might consider that the "size of an entity" should include the size of all its index entries. Depends what you're using the size for.

Comment: If anybody wants to do the same thing with ndb: len(entity._to_pb().Encode())

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the "Datastore Statistics" page in the [Admin Console](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/theadminconsole.html) of your app?  It tells you all kinds of things about your entities, though they are estimates/averages, not exact numbers.